# When creating a Windows Service, is it possible to use the new .csproj format?

Tags: c#, windows-services, csproj

when I use VS to create a Windows Service project, it uses the old .csproj format, which means I have non-transitive "dependencies" instead of transitive "References." I'm wondering if there is a way to use the new .csproj format?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried creating a console app project and using a library like TopShelf? Does that arrange your CSPROJ how you prefer?

Comment: You can edit the csproj file once created to use the new Sdk. Just Google "convert csproj to new format". There should be several worthwhile links near the top

Comment: Got this working? (sure building isn't a problem, but the Window Service should work well after installation)

Comment: Yes. See Pinkfloyd comment above.

Comment: Use [CsprojToVs2017](https://github.com/hvanbakel/CsprojToVs2017) tool